# Xamarin Form traer el id de un registro al dar click

Tags: xamarin

Saludos amigo y gracias por su tiempo. soy nuevo en xamarin xd.
tengo un carrusel de imagenes(el mismo lo lleno con datos de una api), lo que quiero es conseguir el ID de la imagen a la cual se le dio click.

```html
public async void GetAnime()
        {
            var array = await anime.GetAnime<Anime[]>();
            //llenamos el carrusel en este for
            foreach (var item in array)
            {
                CarruselAnimeArray.Add(item);
                IdAnime = item.Id;
            }
        }
```

GetAnime() es la funcion de la vista que trae los datos para mostrarlo. intente crear el IdAnime y llenarlo dentro del foreach, pero el problema aqui es que siempre me da el ultimo id de la base de datos.

```html
   private async void ImgClick_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var item = (Anime)sender;
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new PagesAnimeDetail(IdAnime));
        }
```

este es mi evento click. intente castiar var item = (Anime)sender; pero siempre me da error en ese casteo.

```html
        <CarouselView ItemsSource="{Binding CarruselAnimeArray}" PeekAreaInsets="100" Loop="false">
            <CarouselView.ItemTemplate> 
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout>
                    <Frame HasShadow="True" BorderColor="Red" BackgroundColor="Black"
                           CornerRadius="5" Margin="10" HeightRequest="300"
                           HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand">
                            <StackLayout>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Title}" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="White"
                                       FontSize="Medium" MaxLines="1"
                                       HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" />
                                <ImageButton Source="{Binding Img}" Aspect="AspectFill" 
                                       HeightRequest="150"
                                       WidthRequest="150" HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                       x:Name="ImgClick" Clicked="ImgClick_Clicked" >
                                </ImageButton>
                                <Label Text="Ver Ahora >"  TextColor="Red"
                                       FontSize="Small" Margin="0,10,0,0"
                                       HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" />
                           
                            </StackLayout>
                    </Frame>
                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
           
            </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
            
        </CarouselView>
```

agradezco su ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

ya di con la solucion y aqui la dejo por si alguien mas le pasa lo mismo que a mi.

en la vista
<ImageButton CommandParameter="{Binding ID}"

en la parte de c#

```html
  private async void ImgClick_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ImageButton button = (ImageButton) sender;
            string Id = button.CommandParameter.ToString();
await Navigation.PushAsync(new PagesAnimeDetail(Convert.ToInt32(Id)));
        }
```

espero y les funcione :).